# Tkinter Placing And Deleting A Label

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to display a message saying "Hi"
after a couple seconds, i want that message to go away and open a different file
https://hastebin.com/uhafehizok.vbs
so if its true I want it to place the label, wait two seconds, and then destroy it, but the Tkinter window is waiting two seconds to start, and then starting without any label
any ideas

Comment: Please always post your code in the main text, there is no reason not to.

Comment: Sorry, this is my first ever post. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code, the label is placed, and after 2 seconds it is destroyed. It is never actually shown in your window however as it is not updated.
This is as when entering Tk's `mainloop`, it updates the window in a loop, checking if changes have been made. In your case, you are preventing this check by using `time.sleep`.

With Tkinter, when wanting to have timings you should always use the `after` method, to arrange everything in terms of Tkinter's mainloop (This uses milliseconds).

To fix your code, you could add `root.update()` after placing your label. The `time.sleep` would still freeze up the mainloop whilst it is waiting however, so a better solution would be to remove the call to sleep, and instead call `destroy` on your label after 2 seconds.

This would look like `root.after(2000, letsgolabel.destroy)`.

*Note that I have been referring to root as your access to `tk.Tk()`, as this is normally used.